# Transferring records in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Iam a newbie to hibernate , i am writing a program using hibernate,(The database uses 2 tables)this code performs basic create ,update,delete operations on both the tables in the database

My problem is i dont know how to perform an operation such that one record from one table is cut and pasted as new row in the second table. Is there an hibernate command to do so ?! Or how do you achieve this ?
Iam using session Factory . Also the tables are structurally the same, there cant exist a foreign key relationship between the 2 tables
(so basically the mappings wont work either)
Any help will be truly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know of no built-in Hibernate command for cut-n-paste. Hibernate just gives HQL for that matter.

You should:

1. Retrieve the entities using Hibernate;
2. Transform them to the desired other entity type. Manually, yes.
3. Save the new entities via `session.save`.
4. Delete the old entities via `session.delete`.

**Notes**

1. If you're doing this for lots of records, this naive algorithm isn't performant. For performant bulk save / delete operations [your choice](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch04.html#d0e1932) would be [StatelessSession](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/javadocs/index.html?overview-summary.html)
2. First save and only afterwards delete, so that if your application crashes in between no data is lost.
3. Don't forget to make it transactional if it is forbidden that these entities will show up in both tables.

Comment: Hey yair , how do you transform one entity to another entity manually ?